# Date issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I want to parse date in my page to Javascript's `Date`.

So I have this in my page

```
<span>01-07-2012 01:04 PM</span>
```

And I have Javascript code that parses this value to date

```
var tagText = $(this).html();
var givenDate = new Date(tagText);
alert(givenDate);
```

And here is what I get in different browsers

**IE:**

> Sat Jan 7 13:04:00 UTC+0400 2012

**Chrome:**

> Sat Jan 07 2012 13:04:00 GMT +0400 (Caucasus Standard Time)

**Firefox:**

> Invalid Date

Why Firefox doesn't recognize my date? What I must change to make it work with all major browsers?

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mgER5/1/

Comment: what version of firefox are you using? this works fine in the new version

Comment: 9.0.1 ... I guess, it's the latest version.

Comment: ah ok I have 8.0 I'll upgrade now and let you know

Comment: I just tested it on 9.0.1 and it works. result: "Sat Jan 07 2012 13:04:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

Comment: Do you test with this format? <span>01-07-2012 01:04 PM</span>

Comment: no I tested with the one you provided earlier, wait a sec I'll test with this one

Comment: I can't change that format, because that part is generated automatically. With "/" it works, I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
var tagText = $(this).html();
tagText = tagText.replace(/-/g, '/');
var givenDate = new Date(tagText);
alert(givenDate);
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work with different regional settings in the client's computer?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? this will work with dates like 01-07-2012 .... and those like 01/07/2012 ....

Comment: plus you and I are in different regions (I'm in GMT-5 and you are in GMT+4) and it works for both of us ;)

Comment: I mean, if you change your Regional settings from Control Panel in your PC(change date format to yyyy-dd-mm from yyyy/dd/mm for example), is there any scenario to have that issue again?

Comment: no, it will work. the only problem was the '-' that firefox doesn't read correctly so changing them to '/' did the trick

Comment: Perfect solution, Thank you @redmoon7777

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) the string you are passing to the constructor of the Date object should be:

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
> recognized by the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method ([IETF-compliant RFC 1123 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)).

Basically it should represent an RFC822 or ISO 8601 date.

Answer (score 0):

> What I must change to make it work with all major browsers?

Write it in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want full cross-browser support for *any* date format, you should take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  It allows you to be explicit about the input format.  For example:

```
var m = moment('01-07-2012 01:04 PM', 'DD-MM-YYYY  hh:mm a');
```