# Date string conversion to unix timestamp in JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix-timestamp

I have date string in this format:

```
2009-07-15 00:00:00 - 2009-07-15 08:16:23
```

Could anyone help me to tweak the date string to unix timestamp into something like this:

```
1247634000 - 1247663783
```

I am using `GMT-5` Timezone.

What JavaScript or jQuery techniques could be used?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var input = "2009-07-15 00:00:00 - 2009-07-15 08:16:23";
input = input.split(" - ").map(function (date){
    return Date.parse(date+"-0500")/1000;
}).join(" - ");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LjNbw/1/)

[`Date.parse` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Note: This won't work on old browsers since I'm using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but I think you should easily be able to shim it.

Answer (score 67):

I strongly advise you to use [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) Date lib when working with dates in js. It's really light and awesome.

```
var timeStamp = ( moment('2009-07-15 00:00:00').unix() )*1000
```

Comment: This library does make syntax cleaner and logic simpler.  It seems well worth including this with a date/time focused node.js feature.  6KB minified, for those concerned with including this on the browser side.

Comment: Really. After a whole lot of struggling with the other answers when I tried `moment.js`, it was an immediate peace of mind. Bless the person who created `moment.js`!!!

Comment: This works with NodeJs as well which is a huge plus.

Comment: If Moment.js isn't out of the equation, this should be the accepted answer. Lightweight and super awesome. For those who imbibe Angular, there's an ng version as well (I'm spoiled by it's amCalendar filter, honestly).  It looks like you're trying to get a 'time since x' - I used this for that, using moment: 


`Math.floor((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - moment(timestamp).unix());`

Comment: I didn't need to multiply by 1000. The following returned a perfect timestamp: `moment('2009-07-15 00:00:00').unix()`

Comment: Sadly, moment.js has been deprecated. https://sebastiandedeyne.com/moment-js-thank-you-for-your-service/

Answer (score 22):

in Javascript you can directly pass the string to Date object constructor, like

`var date = new Date('2009-07-15 00:00:00'.split(' ').join('T'))`

that will give you date object and to get timestamp from it you can do

`date.getTime() / 1000`

dividing by 1000 because `getTime` will give timestamps in milliseconds

[Working Demo](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpas/2)

**NOTE:**

Firefox is not able to parse the given date time format, so we need to convert it into proper format first, for that we just need to replace space between date and time component with 'T' that will make it a valid ISO 8601 format and firefox will be able to parse it

Reference:

[Date.parse in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

[ISO 8601 Date Format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

[Same question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831338/date-issue-in-firefox)

Comment: ok, firefox somehow isn't able to parse the dateformat, it expects only one of these formats http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: yes, it works :) another way is to replace the dashes with slashes: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpas/3

Comment: Your answer has just helped with fix an issue with my ap on LG webOS. for some reason their system cannot parse a typical date string such as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss without the "T" in there.

Answer (score 0):

using split method you can change the datetime formate in to date, its very simple and easy to everyone.

```
 var str = "2017-05-09T00:00:00.000Z";
 var res = str.split("-",2);
 var res = str.split("T",1);
 var temp=res;
```