# Best method to get double value from datetime in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is the best way to convert datetime to double in jquery? I have used Date.parse. But, it is not correct in few cases. Also,i am unable to pass datetime format for that method.

-
Viji

Comment: The best way is to convert the datetime to unixtime.. And how do you do it? See this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509814/date-string-conversion-to-unix-timestamp-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can simple do `variablename.toFixed(2);` for that.

Example:

```
var num1 = 12312.12312
console.log(num1.toFixed(2)); // Will give 12312.12
```