# Javascript Date Object Timezone issue - different timezones

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm using a date/time picker with a "friendly" display for the input value which I am trying to convert to a javascript date object. When the date is selected, it comes in this format:

> October 21 2013 09:00

Which I then attempt to covert to a javascript object with the following function:

```
function pickerDateToJavascriptObj(dateIn)
{
    dateIn = dateIn.split(/[- :]/);
    dateIn[0] = getMonthNumber(dateIn[0]);
    outDate = new Date(dateIn[2],dateIn[0],dateIn[1],dateIn[4],dateIn[5], "00");
    console.log(outDate);
    return outDate; 
}
```

I have to date pickers on my page a 'from' date and a 'to' date. When I submit the form and console.log the outDates, the dates are correctly converted to an object, however they consistently have different time zones. For the 'from' date, I get in my console:

```
Date {Mon Oct 21 2013 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)}
```

and for the 'to' date, I am getting:

```
Date {Thu Oct 31 2013 09:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)}
```

Notice the difference between standard and daylight time of the 2 dates.

What could be causing this discrepancy?

Here are the 2 inputs:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Date/Time" name="eventStart" id="eventStart" class="dateTimePicker" readonly="readonly">
<input type="text" placeholder="End Date/Time" name="eventEnd" id="eventEnd" class="dateTimePicker" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: Are you using jquery ui datepicker?

Comment: I am, yes. With this time picker. http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are in the UK and using Firefox.

Daylight Saving Time (aka "British Summer Time") [ends on Oct 27th](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=136&year=2013), so your start date is before the switch and your end date is after.

You are also witnessing [a bug in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16903678/634824) because while the offsets are correct, the names are inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Get the date formatted like this (instead of parsing manually):

```
var myDate= $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

API Doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Get the time formatted like this:

```
var myTime = $.datepicker.parseTime('HH:mm:ss', $("#datepicker").val());
```

API Doc: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-formatting